# Why is Dynamic_Predicate not working?

Tags: integer, ada, contract, gnat

I started to learn Ada yesterday but I don't really understand the `Dynamic_Predicate`'aspect.
when declaring:

```
type evenInt is new Integer
 with Dynamic_Predicate => evenInt mod 2 = 0;
```

Why is it still possible to:

```
anOddNum : evenInt := 7;
```

since:

```
Dynamic_Predicate => evenInt mod 2 = 0
```

forbids to declare odd numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile with assertions enabled (`-gnata`)

Comment: Note that this is specific to GNAT. It looks like you can use `pragma Assertion_Policy` to control this in manner that should be portable to other implementations.

Comment: One could say it's a mistake on the part of GNAT for the assertions to be disabled by default given they chose to use assertions as the mechanism for aspects.